# What is this code doing?

Tags: c#, .net

Could someone please explain to me what the following lines of code do?

```
dynamic shellApplication = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"));

string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);

dynamic directory = shellApplication.NameSpace(path);
dynamic link = directory.ParseName(fileName);

dynamic verbs = link.Verbs();
```

I've searched the msdn library, but couldn't really understand what it did.

This isn't the full code, but I undertand the rest, it is just this part that I'm struggling with.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Are you asking what the purpose of the code is, or how "dynamic" works, or what?  What exactly is the part that is confusing to you?

Comment: The part that is confusing me is: What is the purpose of calling this code and what is the final result it is giving you? Final result being the verbs variable. And what is the first line of the code for? what is "shell.application"?

Comment: "shell.application" is how you create this object here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774094. The "Verbs" member is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787850

Comment: YEAH!!!! I GOT IT!! =D The verbs are all the commands listed in the right-click menu of the targeted file. Meaning i can execute any of those commands from my application by looping through the verbs variable and using the verbs.Item(i).DoIt(); method!
Thanks for all the help everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it is retrieving the shell actions that a particular program is associated with.  For example Open, Print, Edit, etc.

Open regedit and navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\textfile

Expand it out and look at the Shell key.  The code should be returning verbs similar to that.

Comment: so lets say the code was getting the actions for a .exe, would it also include the "pin to task bar" action?

Comment: @Zrean Tofiq: Don't know, but my guess is no.  I believe the Pin to Task Bar method is defined at the system level.

Comment: ok, thank you, but it does have the pin to taskbar method. i am using it right now, but i just wanted to see that we were on the same track =)

Answer (score 4):

This creates `"Shell.Application"` COM object and then uses `dynamic` to call methods on it.

It gets all the verbs that can be called on a file.

This is basically `scripting`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787850%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774160%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)  for a sample.

Comment: What do you mean by "all the **verbs** that can be called on a file"? What are verbs in this situation?

Comment: No on that particular file. See links I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Aliostad's answer, the `dynamic` keyword in C# allows you to call members and methods on an unknown type. This means using a `dynamic` variable you won't get intellisense since the compiler has no clue what members or methods the variable actually has. This is all figured out at runtime.

Here is a [good explanation](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/C4AndTheDynamicKeywordWhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx).

Comment: I didn't have any big problems understanding the dynamic keyword. the problem for me was the shell.application part and i wanted to know what the verbs variable was and where it came from. but thanks anyway =)